# How to set Dashed Grid in graphView?

Tags: android, android-graphview

Now i'm using LineGraphView like,

```
    GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this.getActivity(), "GraphView");
```

this draw line Grid .. but i want dashed line for graphview grid..
i am using jjoe64 graph android that is Graphview-3.1.3.jar

there is any method for that.. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could override the LineGraphView drawSeries and change the paint object.

Something like that:

```
GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this.getActivity(), "GraphView") {
   @Override
   public void drawSeries(Canvas canvas, GraphViewDataInterface[] values, float graphwidth, float graphheight, float border, double minX, double minY, double diffX, double diffY, float horstart, GraphViewSeriesStyle style) {
      paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,20}, 0));
      super.drawSeries(...);
   }
};
```

Comment: can you answer this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260218/make-grid-lines-invisible-android-graphview