# How to make Grid Lines invisible in Android GraphView?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I just want to show only X Y axes and labels on these axes and don't want to show grid lines in **Android `GraphView`**. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you found out how to do this, I'm really interested

Comment: Any answers for the above questions?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the following call should do the trick :

```
your_graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle( GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE );
```

*Please do note I haven't tested the above call :)*

Comment: this command will also remove both horizontal and vertical axis also :)

Comment: Have you tried running this command and then explicitly asking for the X and Y axis to be visible (maybe via    your_graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHighlightZeroLines( true ); or     your_graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsVisible( true );) ?

Comment: i created an issue for this topic, will be fixed in future https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/398

Answer (score 4):

If you use this all the grid lines will be Removed

```
your_graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle( GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE );
```

For Setting Horizontal Line visible

`your_graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.HORIZONTAL);`

For Vertical Line visible

```
your_graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle( GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will remove the grid and then show the X and Y axis

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE);
graph.getViewport().setDrawBorder(true);
```