# How to print graph without excess lines

Tags: java, android, graph, android-graphview

I use graphview library on my android project. I made a graph, but i want to remove this lines [i marked them with black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mo4V.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Grid Lines Invisible Android GraphView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260218/make-grid-lines-invisible-android-graphview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.html), something like this should work:

```
    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE)
    graph.getViewport().setDrawBorder(true);
```

Comment: You have a typo -- `Broder` instead of `Border`. Also, see if you have the right version : `compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'`

Comment: Thank you very much! I had an old version of this library.